set widget field_value with PyMuPDF (fitz) does not work
I have a simple script that should fill AcroForms inside a PDF file.
import fitz  # PyMuPDF


def fill_pdf_form(input_pdf, output_pdf, data):
    doc = fitz.open(input_pdf)

    for page_num in range(len(doc)):
        page = doc.load_page(page_num)
        for widget in page.widgets():
            field_name = widget.field_name
            print("fieldName: ", field_name)
            if field_name in data:
                widget.field_value = data[field_name]
                print("fieldValue1: ", data[field_name])
                print("fieldValue2: ", widget.field_value)

    doc.save(output_pdf, use_objstms=1)
    doc.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_pdf = "file.pdf"
    output_pdf = "file_filled.pdf"
    data = {
        "field_01": "123456 _ggtl",
        "field_multiline_01": "lorem Ipsum\nnext line\nagain a line",
    }
    fill_pdf_form(input_pdf, output_pdf, data)
    print(f"success: {output_pdf}")

fieldValue1 and fieldValue2 are OK on output line. But the saved PDF has no values ​​in the form fields.
What do you have to do to ensure that the set values ​​are included in the output PDF?

Try adding widget.update() after setting the field_value. ie, after this widget.field_value = data[field_name]

thanks. But now i see the text in the "one line" form field only if i click on it. If i click elsewhere the text is not visible in the "one line" form field. A multiline form field show me the text all the time. This behavior is also in the saved PDF file.

What is your version of PyMuPDF? Potentially you should report this behavior in the repository's issue system.

My Version of PyMuPDF is 1.24.9
